# Obtaining Wisdom in the Bible

Tags: textual-discrepancies, wisdom, proverbs, book-of-james

In James 1:5 it says that God gives Wisdom, whereas in Proverbs 4:7 it teaches to seek wisdom.

How would one reconcile these two verses.

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, I'm having difficulty understanding your question.  Could you expand or clarify a bit? In particular, why is it not clear that one can seek what God gives? When you get a chance, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: @Nathaniel I think he means to ask why are we instructed to seek (as in seek after, search out, or work to attain) wisdom, if we are told that it is given to us (as in given freely as a gift, without requiring work).

Comment: What's to reconcile?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following passages:

> Psalm 37:4 "Delight yourself in YHWH, and he will give you the desires of your heart.
>
> Deuteronomy 4:29 "But from there [among the world] you will seek YHWH your God, and you will find Him if you search for Him with all your heart and all your life."
>
> Jeremiah 29:11-14 "For I know the plans I have for you,” declares YHWH, “plans to prosper you and not to harm you, plans to give you hope and a future. Then you will call on me and come and pray to me, and I will listen to you. You will seek me and find me when you seek me with all your heart. I will be found by you,” declares the YHWH, “and bring you out of bondage."
>
> Proverbs 9:10-11 "The fear of YHWH is the beginning of wisdom, and knowledge of the Holy One is understanding. For through me your days will be many, and years will be added to your life."
>
> Psalm 63:1,5 "You, God, are my God, I earnestly I seek you; I thirst for you, my whole being longs for you,
>   in a dry and parched land where there is no water. I will be fully satisfied as with the richest of foods; with singing lips my mouth will praise you."
>
> Hebrews 11:6 "And without faith it is impossible to please Him, for he who comes to God must believe that He is and that He is a rewarder of those who seek Him."

YHWH gives wisdom to those who seek him. Those who earnestly seek him find him, because he reveals himself to them by his Spirit.

> 2 Corinthians 2:6-7,10 "We do, however, speak a message of wisdom among the mature, but not the wisdom of this age or of the rulers of this age, who are coming to nothing. No, we declare God’s wisdom, a mystery that has been hidden and that God destined for our glory before time began. These are the things God has revealed to us by his Spirit. The Spirit searches all things, even the deep things of God.